# EaselJS: Is there any way to export a shape to an image file?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I have a project in CreateJS which I'd like to remake *without* CreateJS, but it seems that all my images are in an EaselJS shape format. For example:

```
this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_1.graphics.f("#465762").s().p("AgOAOQgFgFAAgJQAAgHAFgHQAHgFAHgBQAIABAHAFQAFAHAAAHQAAAJgFAFQgHAHgIgBQgHABgHgHg");
this.shape_1.setTransform(43.4,42,0.747,0.747);
```

Is there some method I could use to export that to an image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export any EaselJS DisplayObject by caching it, and then exporting the dataURL. Note that you have to know the raw bounds. If you want a larger cache of it, just increase the `scale` parameter.

```
this.shape_1.cache(x, y, w, h, [scale]);
var url = this.shape_1.getCacheDataURL();
```

Unfortunately this method does not support the parameters of the Canvas.toDataURL(), so if you want that, you can hit the cache directly:

```
this.shape_1.target.cacheCanvas.toDataURL(…[type], [encoderOptions]);
```

Then, you can use the dataURL in a number of ways. Here is [an article](https://medium.com/better-programming/saving-an-html5-canvas-as-an-image-with-todataurl-f9b7cb61595d) on it. Alternatively, just throw the generated cache into the DOM, and right-click on it to save.

```
document.body.appendChild(this.shape_1.target.cacheCanvas);
```

Docs:

- [DisplayObject.cache()](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache)
- [EaselJS getCacheDataURL()](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_getCacheDataURL)
- [Canvas.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Comment: For the record: in some version of easeljs, there is a source code error/typo/obsolescence: DisplayObject.getCacheDataURL() defers to BitmapCache.getDataURL() [which is not defined]  To resolve, edit & recompile easeljs OR: patch with:     BitmapCache.prototype['getDataURL'] = BitmapCache.prototype.getCacheDataURL;